# Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser not loading name and family name attributes (and others) from Cognito

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

I'm using the Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser method to retrieve the attributes recorded for the logged user from AWS Cognito - but only basic atributes are showing. The ones I want are "name" and "family name", but they don't seem to be loaded in the Promise.

This is only the beggining, but I'm concerned as I will want to retrieve other attributes which are not showing up, like user picture, for instance.

Tried to use currentAuthenticatedUser and currentUserInfo with the same results.

```
  async componentDidMount() {

    await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({bypassCache: true})
                          .then ( user => this.setUserInfo( user ) )
                          .catch( err => console.log(err))


  }
```

```
CognitoUser {
  "Session": null,
  "attributes": Object {
    "email": "r...@gmail.com",
    "email_verified": true,
    "phone_number": "+5...",
    "phone_number_verified": false,
    "sub": "246e9...",
  },
  "authenticationFlowType": "USER_SRP_AUTH",
  "client": Client {
    "endpoint": "https://cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/",
    "userAgent": "aws-amplify/0.1.x react-native",
  },
  "deviceKey": undefined,
  "keyPrefix": "CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.12ddetjn0c0jo0npi6lrec63a7",
  "pool": CognitoUserPool {
    "advancedSecurityDataCollectionFlag": true,
    "client": Client {
      "endpoint": "https://cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/",
      "userAgent": "aws-amplify/0.1.x react-native",
    },
    "clientId": "12ddetjn0c0jo0npi6lrec63a7",
    "storage": [Function MemoryStorage],
    "userPoolId": "us-east...",
  },
  "preferredMFA": "NOMFA",
  "signInUserSession": CognitoUserSession {
    "accessToken": CognitoAccessToken {
      "jwtToken": "e...oJPg",
      "payload": Object {
        "auth_time": 1565137817,
        "client_id": "1...6lrec63a7",
        "event_id": "c3...-4bd9-ad42-200f95f9921c",
        "exp": 15...2,
        "iat": 156...5872,
        "iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/us-east-...",
        "jti": "5483e...544149c42e58",
        "scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin",
        "sub": "246e93...f4d8e6f4725b",
        "token_use": "access",
        "username": "r...f",
      },
    },
    "clockDrift": -2,
    "idToken": CognitoIdToken {
      "jwtToken": "eyJraWQiOiJk...",
      "payload": Object {
        "aud": "12ddetjn0c0j..rec63a7",
        "auth_time": 1565137817,
        "cognito:username": "r..",
        "email": "r..@gmail.com",
        "email_verified": true,
        "event_id": "c3ae..200f95f9921c",
        "exp": ..2,
        "iat": ..2,
        "iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/us-east-..",
        "phone_number": "+5...3",
        "phone_number_verified": false,
        "sub": "246e937..f4d8e6f4725b",
        "token_use": "id",
      },
    },
    "refreshToken": CognitoRefreshToken {
      "token": "eyJjd...",
    },
  },
  "storage": [Function MemoryStorage],
  "userDataKey": "CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.12ddetjn0....userData",
  "username": "r...ff",
}
```

Comment: Did you check the boxes in Cognito -> UserPool -> General settings -> App clients -> Show details -> Set attribute read and write permissions ?

Comment: Sometimes you need a fresh accessToken to see the changes: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2827

Comment: Thanks @ilmiacs! I have checked and all fields are enabled on the app client in cognito. Still when I try to retrieve the attributes, I get only this: ` User Attributes:=================================
Object {
  "email": "r...@gmail.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "sub": "077a3e21-....-ad8f7f2a15ad",
} ` I will check to see if the token changes anything...

Comment: Hi @ilimiacs! Yeap, just confirmed and it doesn't seem to work even using the command from the issue you've mentioned: `        await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({
            bypassCache: true
        }).then(authData => {
            let { attributes } = authData;
            console.log("User Attributes:=================================");
            console.log(attributes);
            return attributes;`     the result is still the same three atributes...

Comment: Perhaps you need the "profile" scope. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-idp-settings.html

Answer (score 0):

To get all user attributes, you may be looking for the Auth.userAttributes() function. To use this you want something like this code:

```
  const authUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
  const attributes = await Auth.userAttributes(authUser);
  // the next line is a convenience that moves the attributes into
  // the authUser object
  attributes.forEach((attr) => {
    authUser.attributes[attr.Name] = attr.Value;
  });
```

If you're still not getting the attributes you need, [take a look here](https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/authentication/managing-user-attributes/q/platform/js/#configuring-standard-attributes), and you can see that you can enable the reading of other attributes from the Amplify command line.

So, in the root of your project:

1. Type "amplify update auth" at the console.
2. Select "Walkthrough the auth configurations"
3. Step through making all the same selections as you've done before.
4. When it asks, "Do you want to specify the user attributes this app can read and write?" it's "Y", and then you select the attributes you want to be able to read.
5. When you finish the wizard, use "amplify push auth"
6. When that's completed, try re-running.

As an alternative to steps 1-4 above, you can also edit cli-inputs.json in the amplify\backend\auth<your auth config name> directory. It's in "userpoolClientReadAttributes". Simply add the attributes you would like to this array (e.g. "name").

This answer was verified with amplify CLI version 8.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to get the picture from google and here is what worked for me - in AWS Cognito Pool under Sign-in Experience choose Google, then add attribute mapping for picture.